# Apex class throwing error that accountId is mandatory

Tags: apex

I wrote an apex class which creates contacts, once contacts are created then I am converting the lead where I am merging with the existing contact but I am getting the following error.

> LeadTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, accountId must be specified if contactId is not null: [Id] Class.LeadTriggerHandler.afterInsertProcess: line 84, column 1 Trigger.LeadTrigger: line 3, column 1

While creating contact, I did not specified accountId which I believe is causing issue in createContactParent() method, I have a process which will auto create accountid for contact so I did not inserted that

Can anyone help me out in this issue if possible please.

```
public class LeadTriggerHandler {

   Static List<Lead> noParentLeadList = new List<Lead>();
   Static List<Lead> parentLeadList = new List<Lead>();
   Static List<Contact> insertConList = new List<Contact>();

    public static void afterInsertProcess(List<Lead> leadList){
List<hed__Relationship__c> insertRelationShipList = new List<hed__Relationship__c>();
List<hed__Affiliation__c> insertaffiliationList = new List<hed__Affiliation__c>();
for(Lead leadKey : leadList){

    if(leadKey.Parent_or_guardian__c == false){
        //list which contains Parent__c = false
        noParentLeadList.add(leadKey);
    }else{
        //list which contains Parent__c = true
        parentLeadList.add(leadKey);
    }
}

if(noParentLeadList != null && noParentLeadList.size() > 0)
    createContactNoParent(noParentLeadList);

if(parentLeadList != null && parentLeadList.size() > 0)
{
    Map<Id,List<Contact>> insertConMap = createContactParent(parentLeadList);
    List<String> acctListName =new List<String>();
    Set<String> otherProgramsValueSet = new Set<String>();
    //contact insert operation
    for(Id idk : insertConMap.keySet()){
        insertConList.addAll(insertConMap.get(idk));
    }
    insert insertConList;
    for(Lead l1:parentLeadList)
    {
        if(l1.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c != null){
        acctListName.add(l1.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c);
        }
        if(l1.Other_Programs_of_Interest__c != null){
        otherProgramsValueSet.addAll(l1.Other_Programs_of_Interest__c.split(';'));
        }
    }

    //setting up inserted contact's Id in RelationShip__c object.
    for(Id IdKey : insertConMap.keySet()){

        hed__Relationship__c rel = new hed__Relationship__c(
            hed__Contact__c = insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(0).Id,
            hed__RelatedContact__c = insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(1).Id,
            hed__Type__c = 'Parent'
        );
        insertRelationShipList.add(rel);
        if(acctListName != null){
        Map<String,Id> accNamesToIdsMap1 = new Map<String,Id>();
        for(Account acc : [select id,Pardot_Program_Name__c from account where Pardot_Program_Name__c in : acctListName]){
            accNamesToIdsMap1.put(acc.Pardot_Program_Name__c,acc.Id);
        }
            for(Id accId : accNamesToIdsMap1.values()){
              insertaffiliationList.add(new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c= accId,
                                                       hed__Contact__c=insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(0).Id,
                                                       hed__Primary__c = true,
                                                       hed__Role__c='Prospect'));
            }
        }
        if(otherProgramsValueSet != null){
        Map<String,Id> accNamesToIdsMap = new Map<String,Id>();
        for(Account acc : [select id,Pardot_Program_Name__c from account where Pardot_Program_Name__c in : otherProgramsValueSet]){
            accNamesToIdsMap.put(acc.Pardot_Program_Name__c,acc.Id);
        }
            for(Id accId : accNamesToIdsMap.values()){
              insertaffiliationList.add(new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c= accId,
                                                       hed__Contact__c=insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(0).Id,
                                                       hed__Role__c='Prospect'));
            }
        }
        List<Id> LeadIds = new List<Id>();
        Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
        Leadconvert.setLeadId(IdKey);
        LeadStatus Leads= [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
        Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(Leads.MasterLabel);
        Leadconvert.setAccountId(insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(0).AccountId);
        Leadconvert.setContactId(insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(0).Id);
        Leadconvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(TRUE); 
        Database.LeadConvertResult Leadconverts = Database.convertLead(Leadconvert);
        System.assert(Leadconverts.isSuccess());


}
    insert insertRelationShipList;
    insert insertaffiliationList;
}
}

  public static Map<Id,List<Contact>> createContactParent(List<Lead> incomingLeadList){

Map<Id, List<Contact>> contactMap = new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
List<Contact> conList=null;

for(Lead tmpLead : incomingLeadList){
        conList = new List<Contact>();
       Contact con = new Contact(
            LastName = tmpLead.LastName, 
            FirstName = tmpLead.FirstName,
           Email = tmpLead.Email
        );
        conList.add(con);

        con = new Contact(
            LastName = tmpLead.Parent_First_Name__c,
            FirstName = tmpLead.Parent_Last_Name__c,
            Email = tmpLead.Parent_Email__c
        );
        conList.add(con);           
        contactMap.put(tmpLead.id, conList);
   }
   return contactMap;
   }


  public static void createContactNoParent(List<Lead> incomingLeadList){

List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
for(Lead ldKey : incomingLeadList){

    Contact con = new Contact(
        LastName = ldKey.LastName,
        FirstName = ldKey.FirstName
    );
    contactList.add(con);
}
insert contactList;
List<String> acctListName2 =new List<String>();
    Set<String> otherProgramsValueSet2 = new Set<String>();
List<hed__Affiliation__c> insertaffiliationList2 = new List<hed__Affiliation__c>();
        for(Lead l1:noParentLeadList)
    {
        if(l1.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c != null){
        acctListName2.add(l1.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c);
        }
        if(l1.Other_Programs_of_Interest__c != null){
        otherProgramsValueSet2.addAll(l1.Other_Programs_of_Interest__c.split(';'));
        }
    }
if(acctListName2 != null){
        Map<String,Id> accNamesToIdsMap2 = new Map<String,Id>();
        for(Account acc : [select id,Pardot_Program_Name__c from account where Pardot_Program_Name__c in : acctListName2]){
            accNamesToIdsMap2.put(acc.Pardot_Program_Name__c,acc.Id);
        }
            for(Id accId : accNamesToIdsMap2.values()){
              insertaffiliationList2.add(new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c= accId,
                                                       hed__Contact__c=contactList.get(0).Id,
                                                       hed__Primary__c = true,
                                                       hed__Role__c='Prospect'));
            }
        }
        if(otherProgramsValueSet2 != null){
        Map<String,Id> accNamesToIdsMap3 = new Map<String,Id>();
        for(Account acc : [select id,Pardot_Program_Name__c from account where Pardot_Program_Name__c in : otherProgramsValueSet2]){
            accNamesToIdsMap3.put(acc.Pardot_Program_Name__c,acc.Id);
        }
            for(Id accId : accNamesToIdsMap3.values()){
              insertaffiliationList2.add(new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c= accId,
                                                       hed__Contact__c=contactList.get(0).Id,
                                                       hed__Role__c='Prospect'));
            }
        }
     insert insertaffiliationList2;
    }
     }
```

Comment: Can you format the code? unformatted code is hard to read and would get very less attention.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, I am not getting any issue in the code so I posted whole code instead of posting bits and pieces so that its easy understand what I exactly did here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your methods never set an AccountId value, so it is always null. You must create or locate accounts and associate them to the contact records before calling `LeadConvert#setAccountId`. You can fix this problem by adding logic to create accounts. Here's one potential solution:

```
public static Map<Id,List<Contact>> createContactParent(List<Lead> incomingLeadList){
    Map<Id, List<Contact>> contactMap = new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
    // Create new household accounts
    Account[] newAccounts = new Account[0];
    for(Lead tmpLead : incomingLeadList){
        newAccounts.add(new Account(Name=tmpLead.LastName+' Household'));
    }
    insert newAccounts;
    for(Lead tmpLead : incomingLeadList){
        Account thisAccount = newAccounts.remove(0);
        contactMap.put(
            tmpLead.id, 
            new Contact[] {
                new Contact(
                    AccountId = thisAccount.Id,
                    LastName = tmpLead.LastName, 
                    FirstName = tmpLead.FirstName,
                    Email = tmpLead.Email
                ),
                new Contact(
                    AccountId = thisAccount.Id,
                    LastName = tmpLead.Parent_First_Name__c,
                    FirstName = tmpLead.Parent_Last_Name__c,
                    Email = tmpLead.Parent_Email__c
                )
            }
        );
    }
    return contactMap;
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping me out in this issue, actually we are using HEDA package so that package will auto create account on inserting contact, so I should do it manually, is there a way to query the contact while converting the lead to fetch accountId

Comment: @user71422 You will need to query the info you need after inserting: `insert insertConList; insertConList = [SELECT AccountId, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE Id = :insertConList];`, then go from there.

Comment: ,can you please help me out a bit more here if possible, I did the query but how can I pass the accountId to setaccountId in lead conversion process

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the required values to LeadConvert.

```
List<Database.LeadConvert> leadsToConvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>(); 
Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(incomingleadId);
lc.setOwnerId(lead/anyownerid);
lc.setAccountId(accountid);  
lc.setContactId(contactid);                
lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
lc.setSendNotificationEmail(false);                
lc.setConvertedStatus('Converted');
leadsToConvert.add(lc);

Database.convertLead(leadsToConvert);
```

You can read more here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_convertlead.htm